# Why is this code not working ? JAVA IN VSCODE

Tags: java, fibonacci

//To print first 10 even terms of fibonacci series but the code won't print the required result, infact it does nothing on being run by vscode

```
class fiboeven {
public static void main(String args[]) {
int a = -1, b = 1, c = 0, e = 0;
while (e <= 10) {
  for (int i = 1; i <= e; i++) {
    c = a + b;
    if (c % 2 == 0) {
      System.out.print(c + " ");
      e++;
    }
    a = b;
    b = c;
      }
}
}
}
```

Comment: Time to learn  how to debug. It will help you in cases you not know why your code is not working

Comment: BTW: Take care of java naming conventions. Class names should start with upper case character

Comment: Please reformat your code before posting it

Comment: Hi and welcome on StackOverflow. Please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

If you print the variables for each step, you will notice that the variables do not change value because of the received values.

```
public class Fiboeven {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int a = -1, b = 1, c = 0, e = 0;
        System.out.println("#1" + a + " "+ b+ " " + c+ " " + e + "\n");
        while (e <= 10) {
            System.out.println("#2" + a + " "+ b+ " " + c+ " " + e + "\n");
            for (int i = 1; i <= e; i++) {
                System.out.println("#3" + a + " "+ b+ " " + c+ " " + e + "\n");
                c = a + b;
                if (c % 2 == 0) {
                  System.out.print(c + " ");
                  e++;
                }
                a = b;
                b = c;
                System.out.println("#4" + a + " "+ b+ " " + c+ " " + e + "\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The program runs but goes into an infinite loop

Because of your condition:

**i <= e (1 <= 0) - in for loop**

#1-1 1 0 0

#2-1 1 0 0

#2-1 1 0 0

#2-1 1 0 0

#2-1 1 0 0

#2-1 1 0 0

#2-1 1 0 0

.........

#2-1 1 0 0

#2-1 1 0 0

Take a look here for a good example https://www.programiz.com/java-programming/examples/fibonacci-series

For the first 10 even number you can discard for-loop

```
public class Fiboeven {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int a = -1, b = 1, c = 0, e = 1;
        while (e <= 10) {
            c = a + b;
            if (c % 2 == 0) {
              System.out.print(e + ":" + c + "\n");
              e++;
            }
            a = b;
            b = c;
        }
    }
}
```

Edit:
result:

```
1:0
2:2
3:8
4:34
5:144
6:610
7:2584
8:10946
9:46368
10:196418
```

Answer (score 0):

It will not work because you have declared

```
e = 0;
//try to add another number like
e = 5;
//it will work
```

see corrections:

```
class fiboeven {
public static void main(String args[]) {
int a = -1, b = 1, c = 0, e = 5; //"corrections: e = 5"
while (e <= 10) {
for (int i = 1; i <= e; i++) {
    c = a + b;
    if (c % 2 == 0) {
    System.out.print(c + " ");
    e++;
    }
   a = b;
   b = c;
}
}
}
```